# Magento 2 session data gets deleted in google chrome

Tags: php, magento, magento2

**Problem:**
When my magento2.3 application redirects user to payment gateway, i can access all the session data. but when it returns backs from there it do not have checkout session data or any session data. this happens only for google chrome

**Things i already explored**
From google chrome release notes (https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site) i can see they have changed samesite default value to "*Lax*", and disabling this works.

**Solution Looking for**
I want to give *samesite=None* value to all my outgoing requests to any third party services. Any help or lead would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try setting the *samesite=None* by following steps..

file : etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie">
        <plugin name="afterGetPath" type="namespace\module\Plugin\View\Element\Js\ManagePath" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

file : Plugin/View/Element/Js/ManagePath.php

```
namespace namespace\module\Plugin\View\Element\Js;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie;

class ManagePath
{
    public function afterGetPath(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie $subject, $path)
    {
        
        if (preg_match('/SameSite/', $path)) {
             $path_array = explode(';', $path);
             $path = $path_array[0];
        }
        
        return $path;
    }
}
```

file :  etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface" type="namespace\module\Session\CustomConfig"/>
</config>
```

file : Session/CustomConfig.php

```
namespace namespace\module\Session;

use Magento\Framework\Session\Config as DefaultConfig;

class CustomConfig extends DefaultConfig
{
    public function setCookiePath($path, $default = null)
    {   
        parent::setCookiePath($path, $default);

        $path = $this->getCookiePath();

        //check and update path of cookie
        if (!preg_match('/SameSite/', $path)) {
            $path .= '; SameSite=None';
            $this->setOption('session.cookie_path', $path);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**NOTE** : replace namespace & module with your ***namespace*** and ***module***.

Comment: Working like Charm.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment on the accepted answer, I must point out that for me it didn't work since Chrome asked that all cookies with SameSite set to "none" to be flagged as secure.
The fix was adding:

```
$path .= '; SameSite=None ; secure';
```

Without flagging them as secure I would have problems adding items to cart.

Worked for me, hope it helps others that encounter same issue.